# generate random String that must Contains alphabets, number and Special Character (6-10 digits)

Tags: java, scala, random, playframework, passwords

I am generating a password which will have 6 to 10 digit.

This is my code which gives me random password of 6-10 digit,

```
val AB = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789:<=>?@_!#%&()*+,-.~";
val rnd = new Random();

def randomPassword(): String = {
    val len = rnd.nextInt(5) + 5
    val sb = new StringBuilder(len);
    for (i <- 0 to len)
       sb.append(AB.charAt(rnd.nextInt(AB.length())));
    return sb.toString();
    }
```

It works fine but the problem is that ***sometimes it gives all numbers or alphabets***.

I want the combination of alphabets and number and special character every time. any suggestion?

Comment: Any particular reason to do so? Any particular number of each you need to fulfill?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson i am developing it for forgot password, and the valid password there must contain alphabets and numbers and symbol and i am mailing this to user email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more idiomatic solution to the problem which provides a better API.

```
object password {
  import scala.util.Random
  import scala.collection.immutable.Stream


  private def gen = Random.alphanumeric

  def get(len: Int): String = {    
    def build(acc: String, s: Stream[Char]): String = {
      if (s.isEmpty) acc
      else build(acc + s.head, s.tail)
    }

    build("", gen take len)
  }
}
```

Lets generate some passwords

```
1 to 25 foreach { _ => println(password get 8) }
```

You will see something like

```
YBk2UrOV
GD4eLexS
l8yxAkp9
ooQnaRpd
NgHAruB8
pMXpi4ad
```

Note: this solution can go a couple of optimization rounds. E.g. `@tailrec`, `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Unlike the question in the title, Random.alphanumeric only generates [A-Za-z0-9] and not special characters. Does Scala offer a similar method to your answer above, only then allowing you to pass your own set of chars?

Answer (score 1):

Generate a random password of all letters first, then replace some of the letters with numbers/special characters as you desire.

(By the way, I'm not familiar with Scala, so I'm going to use Java's syntax, as I wouldn't know whether I'm typing something valid otherwise. My apologies.)

```
// Split source string into letters, numbers, and specials
String AB = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
String numbers = "0123456789";
String specials = ":<=>?@_!#%&()*+,-.~";

String randomPassword() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int len = rnd.nextInt(5) + 5;

    // Generate password with letters first. This part is the same as the original code.
    for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
         sb.append(AB.charAt(rnd.nextInt(AB.length())));
    }


    // Generate an index to replace with a number
    int numberIndex = rnd.nextInt(len);
    // Generate an index to replace with a special character
    int specialIndex;
    do {
        specialIndex = rnd.nextInt(len);
    } while (specialIndex == numberIndex);
    // Replace one letter with a number
    sb.setCharAt(numberIndex, numbers.charAt(rnd.nextInt(numbers.length())));
    // Replace one letter (or the number if you're unlucky) with a special character
    sb.setCharAt(specialIndex, specials.charAt(rnd.nextInt(specials.length())));
}
```

It's a start, and has a flaw (only one number + special character), but it is easily fixable. This solution is also more efficient than generating entirely new passwords if one does not satisfy your criteria, and you're guaranteed to get a password that works when the method returns.

Comment: @LOL Does the for loop go until i is equal to `len`? My mistake. Again, I'm not familiar with Scala... I'm used to starting from 0 and going until `n - 1`.

Comment: @LOL Ah OK. I'll remove that part from my answer and change the loop. My apologies for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

```
def randomPassword(): String = {
    val len = rnd.nextInt(5) + 5
    val sb = new StringBuilder(len);
    for (i <- 0 to len)
       sb.append(AB.charAt(rnd.nextInt(AB.length())));

    if(sb.toString is allString or allNum){
       return randomPassword();
    }
    return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: change the pseudocode to filter the undesired result:
 sb.toString is allString or allNum

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution imho would be (pseudo code)

```
generate password
if no alphabet;
    if not max length;
        add an alphabet
    else
        change last letter with an alphabet
if no digit;
    if not max length;
        add an digit
    else
        change first letter with an digit
if no special;
    if not max length;
        add an special
    else
        change second letter with an special
```

This never reduce entropy unless you already have a max length password.

Answer (score 1):

Using immutable data structures is more idiomatic to scala. The following code works.

```
  protected def nextChar(): Char = Random.nextPrintableChar()

  def randomString(length: Int = 10): String = {
    (0 until length).map(_ => nextChar()).mkString
  }
```

edit:
To ensure there's always a number, special character, and alphabet in string, i would generate each category of letters separately then randomly concatenate them in a functional way or simply with Random.shuffle(characterList).mkString =D.

Answer (score 0):

You could do apply the principle of the while loop.

1. Store the appended password into a variable.
2. Use a while loop to check if it doesn't contain a number and/or symbol, if it doesn't, regenerate the password again and store it into the variable.
3. When the while loop breaks automatically, return the variable.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this one, it works for me.

```
$length = 45;
$chars = array_merge(range(0,9), range('a','z'), range('A','Z'));
shuffle($chars);
$password = implode(array_slice($chars, 0, $length));

echo "This is the password: ".$password;
```

An example of output:

```
This is the password: wmU7KaZoOCIf4qn2tz5E06jiQgHvhR9dyBxrFYAePcDWk
```